# Applescript to move a window relative to it's current position

Tags: applescript, window-manager

I want to move the position of a current window 5 pixels up, and 5 pixels right.
I have found code to move a window to a fixed position.
I have found code to get the position of a window.
I can't figure out how to get it all to work together.
I can imagine doing this either by getting the window position into a variable and using the result, or by a position relative command if there is one.
Here's what I have so far, which works but uses a fixed position only.

```
set delta to 5
set screenOneXOffset to -120
set screenOneYOffset to -1300
tell application "System Events"
    set position of first window of application process "Google Chrome" to ¬  
    {screenTwoXOffset + delta, screenOneYOffset + delta}
end tell
```

How to get the position of a window (but then not sure how to use it):

```
tell application "System Events" to get properties of window 1 of application process "RStudio"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to move the position of a current window 5 pixels up, and 5 pixels right.

I do not have **RStudio**, however, here is an *example* using **Google Chrome**.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
if not running of application "Google Chrome" then return
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Google Chrome"
        if not (exists window 1) then return
        set |position| to position of window 1
        set position of window 1 to ¬
            {((item 1 of |position|) + 5), ((item 2 of |position|) - 5)}
    end tell
end tell
```

**Notes:**

Since you didn't state how you intended to implement the **AppleScript** *code*, I've included some *error handling* that may not be necessary, e.g. `if not running of application "Google Chrome" then return` (Or whichever *application* you set it for.)

Once a *window* had been repositioned to where it meets the bottom of the *menu bar*, or top of the screen if the *menu bar* is hidden, it will no longer move *upwards* and will only continue to move to the *right*.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the same thing in a clunkier way ;))
I used Safari rather than Chrome or RStudio.

`properties` is a huge list, most of which you don't need. You can just get `position` which is a simple list of two integers `{x, y}`
You can capture any result using `result`
My struggle was to capture both, `item 1` & `item 2` of `result`, which I completely failed in, until I first set them to a variable `Pos` which I could then call from. I'm sure someone else could figure how to get around that in one step.

```
tell application "System Events" to get position of window 1 ¬
    of application process "Safari"

set Pos to result
set posX to item 1 of Pos
set posY to item 2 of Pos
set delta to 5

tell application "System Events"
    set position of first window of application process "Safari" to ¬
        {(posX + delta), (posY - delta)}
end tell
```

Comment: `result` is a constant, not a list. It retains its value until another [value is generated](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-BAJBDEJI). Getting `item 1 of result` generates a new result… which in this case, does not have an `item 2`, which results in the -1728 error, i.e. 'object doesn't exist'.

Comment: @Mockman - thank you. I've been tinkering with Applescript for 20 years & it never ceases to throw me curve balls ;))

Comment: It's odd, to be sure. While I can't claim to be much more than a novice with it, the little I do know makes me think that other languages look strange in comparison.